# How do I return something as true or false when I have an if() statement?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I don't exactly know how to word this, but I want to know how to return whether something is true or not depending on what the if statement below determines. I'm sorry if you can't understand what I'm asking, but if you look at the code I think you will understand what I'm asking.

**Code**

```
public boolean isFinished()
    {
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
    if(box[row][column].getValue() != 0)
            {
                if(box[row][column].getValue == box[row][column+1].getValue() && box[row][column].getValue == box[row][column+2].getValue())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if(box[row+1][column].getValue == box[row+1][column+1].getValue() && box[row+1][column].getValue == box[row+1][column+2].getValue())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                 else if(box[row+2][column].getValue == box[row+2][column+1].getValue() && box[row+2][column].getValue == box[row+2][column+1].getValue())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                 else if(box[row][column].getValue == box[row+1][column].getValue() && box[row][column].getValue == box[row+2][column].getValue())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                 else if(box[row][column+1].getValue == box[row+1][column+1].getValue() && box[row][column+1].getValue == box[row+2][column+1].getValue())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                 else if(box[row][column+2].getValue == box[row+1][column+2].getValue() && box[row+1][column].getValue == box[row+2][column+2].getValue())
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                 {
                     return false;
                 }
            }
            //return whether it's true or false
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already returning `true` for `box[row][column].getValue() != 0`. In any of those branches, once `return` is hit, the JVM returns from that *method*, not just the if-statement.

Now just add an `else` block to that outer if-then block, that returns something meaningful for your logic.

Comment: but I have to return something in the method.

Comment: @DavidGilly Your last return should handle whatever the correct answer is for when `box[row][column].getValue() == 0`

Comment: @Jason Ah, didn't see that.

Comment: @DavidGilly define a default value. For example, `return false;`. If you don't want to have a default value and it's conceptually wrong to get to that part of the code, throw a `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 0):

simply test your `getValue()` method in a final if statement and then if you get the value you are looking for `return true`.

Answer (score 0):

boolean functions always want something at the end just take the else out and leave return false at the very end it will work. If it get to a return true statement it will pop out of the method before it even hits the false statement at the  end.

Test it using an if statement,

```
if(isFinished){
    //returned true
    //blah blah do something.
}
```